# UPDATE statement with a cross join in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a column which contains a text blob. I want to update some of the values in the text fields by using a mapping table, but I'm not sure if there is a way to do it without cursors. Here is an example:

```
USE Temp;

CREATE TABLE `Temp`.`test_text` (
  `some_text` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='        ';

CREATE TABLE `Temp`.`mapping` (
  `src` VARCHAR(1024) NULL,
  `dest` VARCHAR(1024) NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='     ';

-- test_text has a single column with some_text
INSERT INTO `Temp`.`test_text` 
(`some_text`)
VALUES
('There once was a man named BobFrank. He changed his name to BobDude.');

-- path_mapping has two columns, which contain all the mappings I'd like to do
INSERT INTO `Temp`.`mapping`
(`src`,
`dest`)
VALUES
('BobFrank', 'BobsNewFrank'),
('BobDude', 'BobsNewDude');

UPDATE `Temp`.`test_text` tt, `Temp`.`mapping` mp
SET tt.some_text = REPLACE(tt.some_text, mp.src, mp.dest);

SELECT *
FROM `Temp`.`test_text`
```

Result:

There once was a man named BobsNewFrank. He changed his name to BobDude."

The code above only seems to replace `BobFrank` in the output.
What I would like to see is the value in `test_text` to be after the update:

There once was a man named BobsNewFrank. He changed his name to BobsNewDude.

Comment: Your data is unnormalized, and this is going to make your question hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your current table structure is less than ideal, because the `test_text` table has unnormalized CSV data in it.  This will preclude using most of the database operations which we would think to use here.  I was able to come up with a solution, but it required storing each CSV term in `test_text` in a separate row.  That is, I used the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_text (some_text varchar(55));
INSERT INTO test_text (some_text)
VALUES
    ('"/tmp/BobFrank"'),
    ('"/tmp/BobDude/"');
```

I left the `path_mapping` identical to what you had.  Then, I only needed a fairly simple query:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(t1.some_text, t2.src, t2.dest)) AS output
FROM test_text t1
INNER JOIN path_mapping t2
    ON t1.some_text LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.src, '%');
```

This generated the following output:

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Don't get caught up in the fact that the example is comma delimited, in actuality its a larger document. I'm going to update the question so it's clearer.